# Use Linux screen session with PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, shell, session, execute

I'm new into Linux and that's why I'm asking this question. I have a webserver with PHP and everything installed. It's working fine, but I do run a Minecraft server. I can access the server commands via a screen session:

```
screen -r minecraft
```

then I can enter the commands.

But when I try to get into the screen via PHP like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('screen -r minecraft');
```

and try to echo it, then it'll return this:

```
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

So how can I send commands to that session, because I really want to build some interaction with the server and website ;) So many thanks already! :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use Minecraft Rcon. It is a new function and you can set it up via the server.properties.